# sleep_until doesn't work with steady_clock in MSVC

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Consider this piece of code:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

using namespace std::chrono_literals;

int main()
{
    auto sx = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    std::this_thread::sleep_until(sx + 10s);
}
```

I would expect this code to sleep for 10 seconds; and that is exactly what it does if I compile it with GCC. But if I use Microsoft VS2015, it doesn't sleep at all.

If I change `steady_clock` to `system_clock`, the Microsoft compiler generates code that works as expected (but which presumably is sensitive to `system_clock` adjustments.)

Is this a bug, or have I misunderstood something?

Comment: your code works perfectly in my system. I'm using MSVC2015 Update 2 with windows 10 x64

Comment: Okay; my compiler is not update 2. I'll download that version and see if it fixes the problem.

Comment: OK @elvis.dukaj, upgrading MSVC2015 to _Update 2_ solved the problem! Thank you! If you would change your comment to an answer, I will acknowledge it as the answer to this question. (Or I could just delete the question, if your prefer that.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your code works perfectly in my system. I'm using MSVC2015 Update 2 with windows 10 x64.

I think it's a bug of msvc2015.

Comment: Yes, updating MSVC2015 to _Update 2_ solved the problem.